# setting Environment from a file in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, env

My question is there any way to set up environment variables from a file during Jenkins build. I have a file called .xyz which has env  variables.

I know there is a jenkins plugin but can we do it inside the execute shell box in jenkins??

I tried . .xyz but that doesn't work!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it from inside Execute Shell step, you've got to write a shell script that will read the file line by line and add them to environment variables.

Assuming your properties file is of format:
`var=value`

A very basic version of the script would be:

```
while read line; do
    export $line
done <your_props_file_name
```

The problem is, these variables will only be retained for the duration of that "Execute Shell" build step. Once you move to a different Build step or Post-build step (within the same job), they will be gone. This is Jenkins's cleanup by design.

That's why there is that [**EnvInject**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) plugin, it takes care of maintaining the environment variables between the build steps.